# find pattern in string regular expression c++

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I have the following string : `E:\501_Document_60_1_R.xml`

I am trying to find the pattern `"_R"`

I am using the following :  `boost::regex rgx("[R]");`

But it's not working  : **"Empty Match"**

thank you.

Code:

```
vector<string> findMono(string s)
{
    vector<string> vec;
    boost::regex rgx("[R]");
    boost::smatch match;

    boost::sregex_iterator begin {s.begin(), s.end(), rgx},
          end {};

    for (boost::sregex_iterator& i = begin; i != end; ++i)
    {
        boost::smatch m = *i;
        vec.push_back(m.str());
    }

    return vec;
}


int maint()
{
   vector<string> m = findMono("E:\501_Document_60_1_R.xml");
   if(m.size() > 0) cout << "Match" << endl;
   else cout << "No Match" << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Define `it's not working`. Are you getting an error ? Empty match ?

Comment: Are you sure `string s` contains the path you think it does? When I test it, I match `R`.

Comment: yes the string is contains the path.

Comment: I would recommend running in a debugger to identify the line at which the runtime error occurs. In addition I would consider changing the regular expression to `"_R"`. Perhaps the problem is that no capturing parentheses are in use, in which case the desired expression may be `"(_R)"`. It appears you are getting an exception - could you perhaps provide the exception and stack trace message?

Comment: @PP I ran the debugger and no error occured.  weird i don't get it

Comment: I agree with PP about changing the regular expression, but consider the case where "_R" occurs in the rest of the path (for example, `"E:\501_Document_Reviewed_61_2_R.xml"`. In that case, you'd get multiple matches, so you may want to change the regex to something  more sophisticated.

Comment: @nklauza in the strings I am sure that i wont have mutliple "_R"

Comment: Works fine for me, using regular expressions from the C++ standard library. It took me about ten minutes to patch the code into something that actually compiled; I'm not usually willing to do that, especially since this is **obviously not** the code that's actually showing the problem. Post real code.

Comment: @HaniGoc, run this:

`#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>

using std::vector;
using std::string;

vector<string> findMono(const string& s)
{
  using namespace boost;
  regex rgx("[R]");
  sregex_iterator begin {s.begin(), s.end(), rgx}, end{};
  vector<string> rt;
  for (sregex_iterator& i = begin; i != end; ++i) {
    rt.push_back((*i).str());
  }
  return rt;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  const vector<string>& ms = findMono("E:\\501_Document_60_1_R.xml");
  for (const auto& m : ms) {
    std::cout << m << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}`

Comment: I had to shorten your original example so that it could fit into a comment, but we need to make sure we're on the same page here. On my end, that code prints `R` to standard output.

Comment: I managed to output the R, by using your function.

Comment: @nklauza can you post it as a solution? And if you can, did u know what  am i missing with my fuction?

Comment: That means that aside from adjusting the regex itself, you have a problem elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Give me a moment to clean it up and I'll post it as an answer, sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we discussed in the comments, `"_R"` will technically work for your regular expression given your current data set.

However, I'd strongly consider something more sophisticated to avoid running into problems in the event that your paths contain the sequence `"_R"` elsewhere. It's fairly easy to protect yourself against that problem, it's good general practice, and it will most likely avoid bugs in the future.

Here is a very basic working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/regex.hpp>

std::vector<std::string> findMono(const std::string& path)
{
  boost::regex rgx("_R");
  boost::sregex_iterator begin {path.begin(), path.end(), rgx}, end {};

  std::vector<std::string> matches;
  for (boost::sregex_iterator& i = begin; i != end; ++i) {
    matches.push_back((*i).str());
  }

  return matches;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  const std::string path = "E:\\501_Document_60_1_R.xml";
  const std::vector<std::string>& matches = findMono(path);

  for (const auto& match : matches) {
    std::cout << match << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```